# Software Configuration Management - Has Google Got it Wrong?

Tags: version-control

I am learning about SCM - I have looked at the usual places like wiki and google. But Google Code University gives a funny description of SCM: [Google Code University](http://code.google.com/edu/tools101/scm.html)

It is completely void of any mention of build tools such as ANT which I thought were a key factor in SCM, has Google got it wrong?

Comment: You can version just about any content and it is not always related to build tools. Example: An artist may keep version history on a piece of electronic art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management says this

In software engineering, software configuration management (SCM) is the task of tracking and controlling changes in the software. Configuration management practices include revision control and the establishment of baselines.

So that includes tools like SVN, not necessarily ANT